# Elegant way to write patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I've found myself writing this sort of things:

```
myFnc (MyDataType0 x y z) = someFunction0 (MyDataType0 x y z)
myFnc (MyDataType1 x y)   = someFunction1 (MyDataType1 x y)
...
```

i.e. I need to pattern match against some data constructors and then use entire instance. My current approach is to match data type, getting all its fields, then reconstruct it in body of function. Is there a better way?

Comment: Aren't you better off with `myFnc (MyDataType0 x y z) = someFunction x y z`, etc.?

Comment: @TomEllis, Well, I can rewrite it but I don't see any reason for that. Logically, `someFunction0` should take objects of type `MyDataType0`.

Comment: But `MyDataType0` isn't a type, it's a constructor.  What does `someFunction0` do when passed a value of constructor `MyDataType1`?

Comment: @TomEllis, it is only defined for values of constructor `MyDataType0`.

Comment: OK, so that means it crashes on some inputs.  It's worth thinking whether this is really what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `@`:

```
myFnc d@MyDataType0{} = someFunction0 d
...
```

Comment: `d@MyDataType0{}` even better.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware you could use that notation without named fields. Edited.